# Image resample only works with JPEG files

Tags: php

I've implemented some code allowing me to resample images to different sizes although at the moment it seems that it only works for JPEGs. I imagine I'd have to add `imagepng($image_p, null, 100);` type pieces of code although this still seems to fail. As for the header I'm not too sure how I could allow for those three file types?

```
<?php
// The file
$filename = 'Channel-Art-Spec.png';

// Set a maximum height and width
$width = 300;
$height = 300;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new dimensions
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($filename);

$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
   $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
} else {
   $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
}

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig,         $height_orig);

// Output
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `imagecreatefromjpeg()` you need to use appropriate function for file type you're reading.

`getimagesize()` checks the type and gives `IMAGETYPE_XXX` in `imageinfo` array ([see the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)).

You can also use a bit less efficient `imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filename))`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code works only for JPEG images is the following line in your code:

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
```

For PNG images use [`imagecreatefrompng`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php).